# How to use AMP-HTML to deep link with your native android app, so that on Google's Search page that url opens my app instead of my amp webpage?

Tags: deep-linking, amp-html

I have built a fully enabled responsive AMP website and I also have a native Android application for the same. I want to deep link the AMP site to my android application using the manifest approach so that whenever a user clicks my link from the Google Search Page, it opens the android app rather than the AMP site. Are there any possible workarounds or methodologies for this?

If it is not possible, why do you think Google does this?

Answer (score 1):

Since AMP is essentially a web technology, the preference is given to AMP page instead of Android app from the search page. There's no way currently where you can surpass the AMP page and directly take the user from SERP to native app. 
There are couple of things you can do as a workaround (if you definitely want it that way):

1. Have a link on the AMP page which takes the user to the deep linked android activity. (Of course, bad user experience due to multiple hops)
2. Remove the AMP page. (This comes with a pinch of salt. Take your wise decision)

**Note** - This information is as per my current understanding and personal knowledge. This by no means is an official communication. Thanks!